# Why is time.sleep pausing early?

Tags: python, time

I'm teaching myself python with the aid of Head First Programming.

I thought I might tweak their example more to my liking, but I think I'm missing something about time.sleep.

My code is

```
print("Welcome to SuperBeans!")
time.sleep(3)
answer = input("Do you need a price now? y/n: ")
```

But rather than pausing for three seconds after the welcome message, it waits 3 minutes, then displays both the message and the input request. What am I missing?

Additionally, the program seems to hang indefinitely when running the "poll" function I defined, without ever displaying the "polling..." notice. I know get_price() is working because it prints it in another section ...

```
def poll():
    price = 99.99
    print(price)
    while price > 4.74:
        print("Polling...")
        price = get_price()
        time.sleep(5)
    print("Buy!")
```

So why is the welcome pausing before I think it should be, and why is the poll() function hanging?

Comment: When I run your first block of code, it sleeps for about three seconds.

Comment: it's the stdout buffer not being flushed

Comment: That is the correct way to call `time.sleep` and your code snippets work fine here on OS X.  Do they work for you if you run them alone, without the rest of your program's code?

Comment: Huh ... odd. I was running it from notepad++ console with nppexec. I just tried running it from IDLE and it worked fine. I guess that solves one question, the new one would be why didn't it work right from npp?

Comment: @Daniel Ball: When you run it interactively then stdin/stdout are line-buffered otherwise a fixed buffer is used. Compare `python -c'import sys; print sys.stdin.isatty()'` and `echo abc | python -c'import sys; print sys.stdin.isatty()'`.

Comment: What does it mean to "run it interactively?"

Comment: @Daniel Ball: `.isatty()` answers it in this context. The intent is whether a human reads/writes or input/output is connected to a file/pipe/etc.

Comment: Only sort of related (and this will be my last question so I don't get in trouble for a long converstion here ;)) What is "abc" after echo supposed to do?

Comment: @Daniel Ball: `echo abc` should print `abc`, e.g., `echo -n abc | python -c'import sys; print sys.stdin.read()[::-1]'` prints `cba`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments above, Python output is being buffered, so the programs run (and sleeps for the right time etc) but you don't see the output for a while.

If you're running Python from a nonstandard console, you need to pass the "-u" option to Python to disable the buffering.  I.e.:

```
python -u foo.py
```

Comment: I put that in the run line for nppexec and it worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About why is `poll()` function hanging, this may be because it stays in the `while` loop.

So question: is `get_price()` ever returning something strictly greater than `4.74` ? (hint: print the value returned)

Comment: It does eventually, yes. The issue is that while it's in the while loop, it's not printing "polling..."