# Python time.sleep in Spyder: how to pause between print statements?

Tags: python, time, ipython, spyder

Edit: the linked post does not solve this problem, this is still an outstanding issue.

I execute the following program in Spyder with iPython:

```
import time

print "Please enter your name."
userName=raw_input();
print "Now let's wait a few seconds, {}.".format(userName)
time.sleep(1)
print "Did you lose your patience?"
```

It prompts the user for their name, then (instead of printing the first line, waiting, and then printing the second line), it pauses and then prints the outputs of the last two print statements at the same time.

When I run from the command line, it works as expected. So does anyone know what I can do so that the script shows the desired behavior from within Spyder/iPython (I am working in Windows 7, Spyder 2.2.5 running iPython with Python 2.7).

Note because I get the expected behavior when I run from the command line, the suggestion at [Why is time.sleep pausing early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031410/why-is-time-sleep-pausing-early) is not transparently applicable, but perhaps it is easy to port that solution to this case? Also, running 'sys.stdout.flush()' before the sleep command doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try calling `sys.stdout.flush()` before sleeping.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031410/why-is-time-sleep-pausing-early?rq=1

Comment: @vanza that didn't do anything.

Comment: @schodge that page says to run the script with 'python -u foo.py' but I am running from Spyder using iPython, not the command line. Is there a way it can be done from within the script itself (or any Spyder gurus here)?

Comment: unrelated: `raw_input` accepts `prompt` attribute. Use it instead of `print`: `userName = raw_input("Please enter your name.\n")`

Comment: @neuronet: first, make it work from the command line, to make sure that your code is correct. Then you could try in `ipython`, `spyder`, to see whether it breaks things

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it worked fine from the command line (even without interposing sys.stdout.flush), so perhaps this is something I should bring to the Spyder/iPython people? Perhaps not appropriate for SE?

Comment: [edit] your question and include that info there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in Spyder and vanza's solution works for me.  Are you sure you put sys.stdout.flush() in the right line? It should look like this:

`vanza's solution:`

```
import time
import sys

print "Please enter your name."
userName=raw_input();
print "Now let's wait a few seconds, {}.".format(userName)
sys.stdout.flush() # <- *** it goes here ***
time.sleep(3)
print "Did you lose your patience?"
```

You might want to scroll down the iPython console a bit before entering your input, to see the text clearly (otherwise it stays a bit low to be noticed).

Comment: Holy !@#. It was the latter problem: it was printing but the console wasn't scrolling correctly...So *that* is the bug, not a bug in the behavior of pause.

Comment: This is on the 'to fix' list for iPython now....http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1773